# Angular - Click Event on Images inside of [innerHTML]

Tags: angular, angular11

I have an application where users can write notes and, in these notes, they can include an image. Sometimes these images are large, and I have CSS that makes them fit into a container.

I am trying to make a click event on any image that may show up in the notes where it will either enlarge the image to see it clearer or open the image in a new tab.

Since the HTML is not written directly in my application, and I get data from the database and display it, I cannot add `(click)="doSomething()"` on the image via HTML.

Users can right click on the image and choose to open it in a new tab. But I am trying to simplify that.

I have found approaches where I can add JS on load events to do action on any image on the page, but that is not what I am looking for. I only want to target any image generated in this component.

If needed, I can create a StackBlitz example, but I am hoping it is something simple that I am just missing.

[image: Notes]

Current HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
  <div class="col-md-12 note-container ql-editor">
    <div
      *ngIf="data.isEnabled"
      [innerHTML]="data.noteText | safeHtml"
    ></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 note-container">
    <div *ngIf="!data.isEnabled">
      <i>This message has been deleted.</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the code you use to render the notes ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the current HTML. I am using [innerHTML] to display the note.

Comment: this could have the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding

Comment: Thanks Juan, I was able to put something together based on that answer and others I found in regards to click events for html in innerHTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 innerHTML (click) binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497824/6559330). This is what worked out for us.

Add `(click)` event to the same div (or element you are using) as the `[innerHtml]`

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
  <div class="col-md-12 note-container ql-editor">
    <div
      *ngIf="data.isEnabled"
      (click)="onNoteClick($event)"
      [innerHTML]="data.noteText | safeHtml"
    ></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 note-container">
    <div *ngIf="!data.isEnabled">
      <i>This message has been deleted.</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then handle the click and check for the image. Currently, for this example I am only checking for base64 images since our rich text editor converts them to base64 when selecting from computer and we don't allow for code editing in the editor.

```js
onNoteClick(event) {
  const imgSrc = event.target.currentSrc;
  if (imgSrc && imgSrc.includes("data:image")) {
    let w = window.open();
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = imgSrc;
    const html =
      "<title>Image</title><style>body {margin: unset} img {max-width: 100%}</style>" +
      img.outerHTML;
    w.document.write(html);
  }
}
```

All other clicks outside of images in the innerHTML get ignored.